# Javascript object still null after assignment

Tags: javascript, json, object, global, variable-assignment

I have a function **setStatus** that I call this way:

```
$.getJSON( '/api/v1/status', setStatus );
```

The function looks like this:

```
function setStatus(data) {
    status = data;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    timer  = setInterval(updateStatus, 1000);
}
```

When I run this the console prints a nice object on the first line containing my data but it prints **[object Object]** for the second line. Later on my **updateStatus** tries to use the data to calculate an uptime value:

```
function updateStatus() {
    var table = $('#status');
    table.find('#uptime').text(calculateUptime(status.bootTime*1000));
```

The table shows a bunch of NaN's, presumable because the variable 'status' is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In setStatus you seem to be assigning `data` to the local variable `status`. Have you defined `status` in global scope?

Comment: @Valdas Rapševičius: I've seen many comments online saying that by leaving that declaration out you automatically create a global. But it doesn't matter because even when I put it in the code still fails. It fails on all of this: "var status;", "var status = null;", "var status = '';", "window.status = data;" and "window.status = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));". I went through a number of different copying tricks with jquery all of which didn't work.